# Unable to add class or id to button in jquery .append() method to make a button that works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

instead of running delete function, i wont to run the button class

```
    $("#app-table").append("<tr><td>"+sernumb+"</td><td>"+person.name1+"</td><td>"+parseInt(person.rollno)+"</td><td>"+person.address+"</td><td><button id='sideb"+r_index+"' type='button' onclick='delete_row(this);'>Delete</button></td></tr>");     // delete button to be added
    });
    $("#btn2del").click(function () {
        $("#app-table tr:last").remove();
    });
    $("#row1del").click(function () {
        $("#app-table tr:nth-child(1)").remove();  // deleting everything but the mentioned item in not
    });
    $("#delete-c").click(function(){
        alert("Its Working");
    });

});
function delete_row(ele){
       var index=$(this).parent().parent().index();
      $("#app-table tr").eq(index).remove();  // deleting current row        
}
```

Comment: have you found right answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete row by :

```
function delete_row(ele){
    var parent_tr=$(this).closest('tr').remove();// deleting current row        
}
```